# Distance from a point to a line : output nan?

Tags: sympy

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad English!

(ref)Distance from a point to a line ＜ wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

```
from sympy import *
var('a b c x y x1 y1 x2 y2 x0 y0 co si tx ty d DH')
x1=0
y1=solve([a*x+b*y+c],[y])[y].subs({x:0})
x2=solve([a*x+b*y+c],[x])[x].subs({y:0})
y2=0
d=sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)
v=solve([co*0-si*0+tx-x1,si*0+co*0+ty-y1,co*d-si*0+tx-x2,si*d+co*0+ty-y2],[co,si,tx,ty])
A=Matrix([
               [v[co],-v[si],v[tx]],
               [v[si], v[co],v[ty]],
               [0   ,     0,     1]
])
B=Matrix([
               [x0],
               [y0],
               [ 1]
])
AinvB=A.inv()*B
DH=simplify(AinvB[1])
print(DH)
print(float(DH.subs({a:1,b:-1,c:10,x0:0,y0:11})))
print(float(DH.subs({a:1,b:-1,c: 0,x0:0,y0: 1})))
# -c*(a*x0 + b*y0 + c)/(a*b*sqrt(c**2*(a**2 + b**2)/(a**2*b**2)))
# -0.7071067811865476
# nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you generate is not always valid for all substituted values. In the case that gives nan your expression generates 0/0 which is nan.

```
>>> from sympy import S, fraction, Tuple
>>> eq=S('-c*(a*x0 + b*y0 + c)/(a*b*sqrt(c**2*(a**2 + b**2)/(a**2*b**2)))')
>>> n,d=fraction(eq)
>>> Tuple(n,d).subs(dict(a=1,b=-1,c=0,x0=0,y0=1))
(0, 0)
>>> _[0]/_[1]
nan
```

You might be interested in using SymPy's geometric objects to help with such calculations and (in this case) compare their expressions to what you generate by other means:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import b,m,x,y
>>> from sympy import Point, Line
>>> d=Point(x,y).distance(Line(m*x+b-y))
>>> d
sqrt((x-(-b*m+m*y+x)/(m**2+1))**2 + (y-(b+m**2*y+m*x)/(m**2+1))**2)
>>> d.subs(y, m*x+b).simplify()
0
```